# jquery.ajax json wrong?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

hey i have a problem submitting my data via jquery and back:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "checkAvailability.php",
    type: 'POST',
    data : {data:JSON.stringify(data)},
    success: function(data) {
        if (data.result == 0) {
            alert("0")
        } 
        if(data.result == 1) {
            alert("1")
        }
    }
});
```

so,
ONE of those if-conditions must be true, because of:

checkAvailability.php:

```
if(isset($_POST['data'])) {
    define('SECURE', true);
    include "storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php";

    require 'AvailabilityChecker.php';

$config = array(etc..);

    $availabilityChecker = new AvailabilityChecker($config);

    $data = $_POST['data'];
    $data = json_decode($data,true);

    preg_match( '/(\d+(\.\d+)?)/', $data['x'] , $m);
    $x =  $m[0];

    if($availabilityChecker->check_availability($x)) {
        echo json_encode(array("error" => "is ok", "result"=>1));
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array("error" => "not ok", "result"=>0));
    }
}
```

data.result have to be 1 OR 0.
anybody can tell me why there is no alert-message? greetings!

UPDATE:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "checkAvailability.php",
    type: 'POST',
    data : {data:JSON.stringify(data)},
    success: function(data) {
        if (data.result == 0) {
            alert("0")
        } else { alert("fail-1") }
        if(data.result == 1) {
            alert("1")
        } else { alert("fail-2") }
    }
});
```

now i get first the fail-1 alert and than the fail-2 alert, so both if-conditions are false, why?

Comment: Are you sure the success callback is happening at all? Are you setting the correct contentType in php since you didn't define a dataType in your ajax options?

Comment: i updated, take a look, there is a callback

Comment: because data is a string and doesn't have a result property. See the second part of my first comment.

Comment: so i should remove the json_encode?

Comment: What does the response 'data' look like? If using chrome/firefox with firebug you can use Console.Log(data); to take a look

Comment: yea i had to add the datatype: "json"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the dataType, otherwise jquery will instead try to guess what you are trying to do. In this case it is incorrectly guessing text/html rather than application/json.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "checkAvailability.php",
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data : {data:JSON.stringify(data)},
    success: function(data) {
        if (data.result == 0) {
            alert("0")
        } else { alert("fail-1") }
        if(data.result == 1) {
            alert("1")
        } else { alert("fail-2") }
    }
});
```

You should also properly set the content-type header in php, before you echo the json.

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

You can get away with doing either-or, but i'd suggest doing both.

Comment: This will work, but it would be good practice to send the correct content type header in your php file

Comment: I'd suggest doing both.

Comment: what you mean user574632?

Comment: yea but i had to write it like this: header: 'Content-type: application/json',

Answer (score 0):

a solution can be

```
success: function(d) {

        data = jQuery.parseJSON(d);

        if (data.result == 0) {
            alert("0")
        }
        if(data.result == 1) {
            alert("1")
        }
    }
```

this becouse $.ajax will no decode the result text from the page for you.
what the php code is doin in fact is to print a json string to the stream.

Note that the the output passed to success can be any sort of text (also xml code on simply text)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the correct content type header in your php file:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
//snip
echo json_encode(array("error" => "is ok", "result"=>1));
```